# Проблемы с импортом в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

Нужна помощь
Вот структура:

```
pakets
| - __init__.py
| - first_palet.py
main.py
```

Вот код main.py

```
from pakets import *

print(eto_epremena)
```

Вот код __init.py

```
__all__ = ['first_palet']
```

Ну а вот код first_palet.py

```
eto_epremena = 'gg good'
```

По итогу код не работает. Можете кто-нибудь починить и объяснить, почему так?

Comment: first_palet.eto_epremena может это так работает?

Comment: Вот я дурак, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы импортируете все модули пакета, но не их содержимое. Вот так нужно:

```
from pakets import *

print(first_palet.eto_epremena)
```